# Mean of lines in data file

Tags: python

I need to make a function that computes the mean of each line of numbers in a data file (.csv) and then returns the means as a list.

I have managed to get values for the numbers added together but I can't figure out how to divide by the length of each line of data and then feed the result into a list to be returned.

```
def line_averages(filename):
    """ compute the average value for every line, and return the average
    values in a list in the file "filename" """
    infile = open(filename, "r")
    all_input = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    lines = all_input.split('\n')       # remove lines
    for one_line in lines:
        values = one_line.split(',')    # remove commas
        line_sum = 0 
        print(values)
        for j in values:
            line_sum = line_sum + float(j)
```

Update:

this is the new code I have as per one of the suggestions below:

```
def line_averages(filename):
""" compute the average value for every line, and return the average
values in a list in the file "filename" """
f = open(filename, "r")
x = f.read()
f.close()
no_lines = x.split('\n')       # remove lines
means = []
for i in no_lines:
    no_commas = i.split(',')    # remove commas
    average = sum(no_commas) / len(no_commas)
    means.append(average)
return means
```

I get this error:

```
In [22]: line_averages("data.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-29-e2e3fddb5de5>", line 1, in <module>
line_averages("data.csv")

File "E:/Google Drive/python_files/training4.py", line 19, in line_averages
average = sum(no_commas) / len(no_commas)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

not sure what's gone wrong?!

Comment: Please show a few lines of your .csv file. Thanks.

Comment: 1,2 \n
1,1,1,1 \n
-1,0,1 \n
42,17 \n
wont let me do them on seperate lines....

Comment: Thanks. It seems though that your question has found an answer... Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return_list = []
...
    average = sum(values) / len(values)
    return_list.append(average)
```

Also, *please* use descriptive variable names.  Single-letter variables are okay for throw-away indices, but not for anything with a lasting meaning.

---

**Spoiler Alert**

```
# If you have the statistics package, use "mean" from that, instead.
def mean(coll):
    return float(sum(coll)) / max(len(coll), 1)

def line_averages(filename):
    """ compute the average value for every line, and return the average
    values in a list in the file "filename" """

    return [mean([int(values) for values in line.split(',')]) for line in open(filename)]
```

Comment: Thank you! yes sorry, I was just kind of brain dumping so should have written out proper variables before posting here.

Comment: Great.  Did these answers get you moving in the right direction?  If so, please up-vote whatever helped and "accept" your favourite, so StackOverflow can archive the issue properly.

Comment: Hi I tried it but got the error as shown above in "Update:"

Comment: You still have to convert the values from string to float.

Comment: Thank you, realized that now :)

Comment: :-)  As you learn more Python, you might revisit this once in a while.  See how short you can make the function.  A lot of these things reduce to a single line of code, once you learn the techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the number of elements on each line can be found with `len(c)`. The easiest way to add these to a list, using your current code, would be to initialize an empty list before your for loop:

```
means = []
```

and then `append` each calculated mean to this list:

```
means.append(s / len(c))
```

There are more efficient ways to do this in general (search for 'list comprehension'), but this should be the fastest way to get you going.